# Webpage fails to render correctly on same version of Chrome but different version of Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, google-chrome, rendering

[Cubes 3D](http://sandbox.chrisloughnane.net/cube3d/)

The above link works perfectly on Windows 7: Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 m

But on XP SP3: Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 m

the cubes are reduced to displaying a flattened number 2.

This behaviour is completely unexpected, could anyone explain why the same browser version is being affected by the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the same browser version is being affected by the OS?

Because the browser is calling underlying system APIs to render the page. In this case with an HTML 5 page the browser is probably using some video acceleration to directly interact with the video card. You don't mention the video card but different cards or drivers could also be a factor.

You can see if hardware acceleration is enabled by going to `chrome://flags` and checking this setting:

> **GPU compositing on all pages Mac, Windows, Linux**
>
> Uses GPU accelerated compositing on all pages, not just those that include GPU-accelerated layers.

Comment: Thanks Brad, 'using some video acceleration' makes perfect sense. Its a very old machine that was given in my new work place. Your answer makes sense.